# some links for graphics in C

Tags: c, graphics

I'm looking for some tutorials which can teach about graphics on C, I tryed find it, but all I can find are discussions about special topics, I'm beginner, thanks in advance

Comment: how about OpenGL?  There is a ton of material about that.

Comment: openGl, I know nothing about it how can I connect it with C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What platform are you trying to work on?

And what are you trying to achieve? "Graphics" can be a lot of things. Are you trying to work on game type stuff? Are we talking 2d or 3d here? Is it image manipulation or just displaying them?

OpenGL and DirectX will let you do pretty much anything you need to do and interface directly to the hardware drivers, but may well be overkill for many things.

Comment: ok, now I want to write something simple on C using openGl, 2d, what can U suggest, I don't know even from which point to start, for expamle how can I draw circle or square using C?

Comment: Unfortunately there is not really any "draw circle" function. You're going to need actually learn some api. If you want to learn open gl, there are a lot of good tutorials available online. However, for 2D stuff openGL may be a bit overkill. Being more specific about your final goal would help a lot.

Answer (score 1):

[SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/tutorials.php)

[Cairo](http://cairographics.org/tutorial/)

If you need something more specific than those then feel free to ask a more specific question.

Comment: I know a lot about programming on C, but I know nothing about graphics on C, from which point to start, maybe book, some materials?